# Reactive array name in Vue methods?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

How can I make the array name reactive?

```js
deleteFoto3(index, item) {
   //index = 3
// this.editedItem.arrayImages +`${index}` //Something like that...
     const index = this.editedItem.arrayImages3.indexOf(item);
     if (index > -1) {
        this.editedItem.arrayImages3.splice(index, 1);
        this.editedItem.NameImages3.splice(index, 1);
     }
},
```

Comment: `this.editedItem["arrayImages" + index]` or `this.editedItem[\`arrayImages${index}\`]`

Comment: Yes thank you. You can add in the answer, I will vote.

Comment: you should avoid having to need to use a 3 in the method/property name and instead use an array.

Comment: You can accept the duplicate at the top of the page

Comment: Also, you should consider using an array instead of using an object with consecutive numeric properties.

Comment: I have four arrays with photos. I work with firebase and it doesn't work with nested arrays.